# Need help recovering data using TestDisk

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk

This is what my partitions looks like now:
[image: partition table]

Earlier the *Unallocated* 20GB space was just after *OS(C:)* partition. I booted to a Linux Mint Live Disk and used Gparted to move the unallocated space after the *150GB Pop OS* and expand it. It crashed midway and after I tried rebooting to Pop OS, I am unable to boot into it. I get `initramfs`. So I booted into Windows 10(works fine) and used TestDisk to recover lost data.

I selected my Drive, selected EFI GPT partition type, and selected Analyse and I got this:
[image: current partition structure]
I couldn't understand anything, So I proceeded to Quick Search and after 5-10 minutes I got this:

```
The harddisk (512 GB / 476 GiB) seems too small! (< 1023 GB / 953 GiB)
Check the harddisk size: HD jumper settings, BIOS detection...                                                                                                                                                                                  
The following partition can't be recovered:                                                                                  
Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors                                                        
>  MS Data               1000215182 1999863068  999647887
```

I proceeded and got this:

```
Disk /dev/sda - 512 GB / 476 GiB - CHS 62260 255 63                                                                          
Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors                                                        
>P EFI System                  2048     534527     532480 [EFI System Partition] [SYSTEM]                                
D MS Data                   567296  623962929  623395634 [OS]                                                           
D MS Data                   567296 1000215182  999647887 [OS]                                                           
D EFI System             623964160  625192959    1228800 [EFI System Partition] [NO NAME]                               
D Linux Swap             625192960  641970159   16777200                                                                
D EFI System             665907200  667135999    1228800 [EFI System Partition] [NO NAME]                               
D Linux Swap             667136000  683913199   16777200                                                                
D Linux filesys. data    683913216  998469631  314556416                                                                
D MS Data                996732929  998473728    1740800                                                                
D MS Data                998473728 1000214527    1740800 [RECOVERY]
```

Now, What should I do?

Comment: You're trying to saw the branch you're standing on. You need to run testdisk from USB & recover to another drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think you are confusing Testdisk and Photorec.  The OP has actually asked a few other questions on this subject, and he is trying to recover from an attempt to resize a partition gone wrong.  I posited that Testdisk should be able to walk back the missing Linux partition - as its worked for me in the past.

Comment: @Tetsujin In fairness, I did not know that he had used gparted to move unallocated space around as this was not mentioned in his previous posts - I assumed he had tried to grow a partition and stuffed up the grub install.  I can see where you are coming from.

Comment: So should I boot from USB?

Comment: @Mayank - As you have moved the partition, rather then just expanding it, Photorec may not be able to help you - and any recovery has just gotten a whole lot riskier because it sounds like there was a crash during the resize, which will have create inconsistencies.   You really need to do a full bitcopy of the disk before attempting recovery (google ddrescue - and yes, this should be done from a bootable USB)

Comment: @davidgo I do not have a spare hardisk to create a copy of the disk

Comment: After cloning the disk, I would try and use a Linux (eg Ubuntu) bootable disk and see if it recognises /dev/sd?5 and allows you to access it.   It is possible that the partition has been expanded but the bootloader can no longer find it [ that is a best case scenario ].   If you are still stuck with the device naming, can you provide the output of "sudo lsblk" (run from a USB boot disk)

Comment: Okay, I'll boot to Linux Mint and try to access /dev/sda5

Comment: @Mayank you can proceed without cloning the disk but what you are effectively saying is "my data is worth less then US$50" - ie the cost of a 1tb hard disk.   Particularly with your level of knowledge you are very likely to stuff up the first attempts to recover, and if you don't have a backup you may be making a bigger hole for yourself.

Comment: @davidgo I'm think so too, maybe I'll just let go of that data. So, I'm booted on Live Disk; This is what I see: https://i.imgur.com/RH8diLh.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127741/discussion-between-davidgo-and-mayank).

Comment: I am missing a precise question about what your goal is instead of questioning "What should I do?".

Comment: @r2d3 Thanks for your interest. I solved it, thanks to davidgo . I'll answer the question myself about what helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore this error and continue:

```
The harddisk (512 GB / 476 GiB) seems too small! (< 1023 GB / 953 GiB)                                         
Check the harddisk size: HD jumper settings, BIOS detection...                                                                                                                                                                
The following partition can't be recovered:                                                                         
Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors                                               
>  MS Data               1000215182 1999863068  999647887
```

Navigate to Linux filesys. data:

```
Disk /dev/sda - 512 GB / 476 GiB - CHS 62260 255 63                                                                 
Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors                                                
P EFI System                  2048     534527     532480 [EFI System Partition] [SYSTEM]                       D MS Data                   567296  683897649  683330354 [OS]                                                  D MS Data                   567296 1000215182  999647887 [OS]                                                 
>D Linux filesys. data    683898880  998471679  314572800                                                       
D MS Data                996732929  998473728    1740800                                                       
D MS Data                998473728 1000214527    1740800 [RECOVERY]
```

Press **`p`** to list files.

Navigate to */home* directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 25-Jul-2021 03:58 .                                                           
drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 25-Jul-2021 03:58 ..                                                                                                      
drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 20-Apr-2021 16:09 dev                                                        
>drwxr-xr-x     0     0      4096 27-Jul-2021 13:09 home                                                        
lrwxrwxrwx     0     0         7 25-Jul-2021 03:56 lib                                                         
lrwxrwxrwx     0     0         9 25-Jul-2021 03:56 lib32
```

Select files to copy using **:**(colon) key and after copying, **C** key to copy the selected files and navigate to the destination to copy files to and press **C** key again to start copying.